# SSO configuration for biztalk 2010 WCF-oracleDB adapter

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have few biztalk 2010 applications. For connecting oracle we are using wcf-oracledb adapter. I am trying to implement Enterprise SSO for connecting  oracle. I have configured SSO by creating affiliate application and assigned it to pipeline. while running interface getting below error

> Error details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unable to redeem ticket, no ticket exists in the message.
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.IBTSTicket.ValidateAndRedeemTicket(Object message, String applicationName, Int32 flags, String& externalUserName)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.ApplyClientCredentials(ClientCredentials clientCredentials, IBaseMessage message)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.CreateChannelFactory[TChannel](IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.GetChannel[TChannel](IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage, ChannelFactory`1& cachedFactory)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage)"

Am I missing anything in configuration? How to resolve this error?

Comment: Are you trying to map the caller from the receive location through to the send port using SSO or are you trying to use SSO Affiliate to store credentials for BizTalk to use?

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom pipeline to attach a sso ticket to your messages.

Refer to this post:

http://blog.csdn.net/cnzee/article/details/7994243

(disclosure: it's my blog post)

Answer (score 2):

Option A: If you are trying to map the caller from the Receive Location through to the Send Port your host need to be trusted.

Option B: If you are using SSO Affiliate to store credentials for BizTalk to use then you need to create the SSO Ticket in the message.

The quickest way to do this is to use the [BizTalk Business Rules Engine](http://brepipelineframework.codeplex.com/) and use the `CreateSSOTicketContextProperty` action.

Let me explain why this is necessary. What the SSO Affiliate was intended to be used for is that you had the caller authenticate against the receive location (e.g. a web service) and the credentials of the caller would be passed through to the send port in a SSO Ticket which would then be mapped using the SSO Affiliate user mapping.  This would happen when you mark the Host as Trusted.

**Update**: A colleague of mine has also said you need to confirm that tickets are enabled on the Affiliate Application in SSO Administration

[image]